# Ideals in quadratic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am studying for an algebra exam and have stumbled upon these two questions:

1. Show that $(2, \varepsilon)$ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$
2. Show that $(2, \varepsilon)$ is a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$

$\varepsilon$ is not specified, but I suppose $\varepsilon = \sqrt{0}$ and $\varepsilon = \sqrt{-1}$ respectively. Here are my thoughts:

1. Isn’t $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}] = \mathbb{Z}$ and hence a PID?
2. I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and that the Gaussian integers are a PID. How could I prove the statement without this fact?

**Edit:** I have found this definition in the lecture notes: Let $A$ be a (commutative) ring, $d \in A$, and $\varepsilon$ a “square root” of $d$ that we add to $A$, then $A[\sqrt{d}] = \{a + b\varepsilon, a, b \in A\}$. <s>That’s why I think $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}] = \{a + b\sqrt{0}, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \mathbb{Z}$.</s>

Comment: I guess the notation is to be interpreted as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}] = \mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 - D\rangle$, and $\varepsilon$ is the residue class of $X$ in the factor ring. Then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$ would not be (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your comment. I understand that $(2, X)$ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$, but I think our interpretation of $A[\sqrt{d}]$ is different, see my edit to the original post. Could you elaborate on the difference of these two interpretations?

Comment: Well, it was a guess to make sense of the assertion that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$ has a non-principal ideal. In the definition from your notes, _what is_ $\varepsilon$? I suspect the intention is that $A[\sqrt{d}]$ shall be $A^2$, with componentwise addition and multiplication $(u,v)\cdot (x,y) = (ux + dvy, uy + vx)$ (which is isomorphic to my guess). But without a specification for $\varepsilon$, we'll never know which guesses are right and which are wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise with my edit. I have given it another try. And yep, you’re right about the definition of the addition and multiplication. But I still don’t get what’s wrong with my interpretation of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$. Sorry if I’m being stupid...

Comment: Indeed, the intention is to always add a new element $\varepsilon \notin A$ that shall satisfy $\varepsilon^2 = d$, regardless of whether $d$ is a square in $A$ or not. So it's meant how I guessed. The clarity with which that is stated is however not overwhelming. And the notation is not quite standard in the case where $d$ is a square (if $d$ isn't a square, we get isomorphic rings with both interpretations of the notation).

Comment: Your interpretation of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$ as $\mathbb{Z}$ makes sense (it's the standard interpretation of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ as the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$), it just isn't the intended interpretation.

Comment: Thank you again, Daniel, for clearing out my misconceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting out the notational difficulties with Daniel Fisher, I am now able to answer my own question:

1. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$: If $(2, \varepsilon)$ was a principal ideal, it would be $(\operatorname{GCD}(2, \varepsilon))$ with $\operatorname{GCD}(2, \varepsilon)$ being a non-unit. However, 2 and $\varepsilon$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{0}]$ and hence $(2, \varepsilon)$ cannot be principal.
2. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ = $\mathbb{Z}[i]$: Here, $(2, \varepsilon) = (2, i)$. $i$ is a unit in the Gaussian integers and hence $(2, i) = (1) = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and a principal ideal.